# Task Scheduler (Win11): is it possible to delay multiple ACTIONS under a single task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a way to delay multiple Actions under a single Task? Something like:

1. Act1: do this, **wait 2 secs**
2. Act2: do that

With "Actions" I mean those under this tab section, where you can stack multiple actions in sequence:

[image]

I know how to use and delay individual Tasks, but I find it a big miss to not have delay options in the Actions tab since you can actually stack multiple actions. For these types of operations with sequential commands with pauses (using sleep.exe for example) can we rely only on batch files?